# Preg_match with Cyrillic doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

`/((?:[a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}0-9]+))(#)(\\d+)/is` 
That's what I recently tried but still doesn't work. I have no idea what else to try.

Comment: post your question clearly. what is your requirement?

Comment: тест#1234 I need to check if the text before `#` is text

Comment: Please give some strings that must match and some that mustn't.

Comment: `test#1234` - match
`тест#1234` - match

`!@№!$№$@#&$ #1234` - doesn't match
`12312312` - doesnt match

Comment: @blako This isn't Java, you don't need to double escape `\\d+`. `\d+` is fine, otherwise you will match a literal backslash followed by `d` one or more times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `u` modifier (for unicode) at the end of the regex:

```
/((?:[a-zA-Z\p{Cyrillic}0-9]+))(#)(\\d+)/isu
//                                 here ___^
```